No aplica estilos CSS al hacer deploy en Vercel
Al hacer el deploy en Vercel de mi aplicación con NextJS y TailwindCSS no me aplica los estilos de CSS, no tengo ideas que puede estar mal en la configuración

fíjate en la consola, si te sale algún error de archivo inexistente, es de decir que esta mal la ruta de tu hoja de estilos.

¿Qué muestra la consola del cliente? Has validado que las URL's que se sirven al cliente sean las correctas y que el servidor despache los recursos correspondientes?

En el localhost si me da estilos, es cuando se hace deploy en vercel

Estás usando el archivo middleware.ts ?
